# Problem in Intersection of Two Linked Lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have used the approach such that:
-> Take two dummy nodes for each list. Point each to the head of the lists.
-> Iterate over them. If anyone becomes null, point them to the head of the opposite lists and continue iterating until they collide.

Why did this code not work?

```
ListNode *getIntersectionNode(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2) {
        if(l1 == NULL && l2 == NULL) return NULL;
        ListNode* d1 = l1;
        ListNode* d2 = l2;
        while(d1 != NULL && d2 != NULL) {
            if(d1 == d2) {
                return d1;
            }
            if(d1 == NULL && d2 != NULL) d1 = l2;
            if(d2 == NULL && d1 != NULL) d2 = l1;
            d1 = d1 -> next;
            d2 = d2 -> next;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Do not tag `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.  You should tag the actual computer language you are using, which looks like either `C` or `C++`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in these lines.

```
if(d1 == NULL && d2 != NULL) d1 = l2;
if(d2 == NULL && d1 != NULL) d2 = l1;
```

These conditions are inside the while loop, and they are not in the correct order. You should first advance d1 and d2 to their next nodes and then check if they become null. Below is a corrected version.

```
ListNode *getIntersectionNode(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2) {

        if (l1 == NULL || l2 == NULL) return NULL;
        
        ListNode* d1 = l1;
        ListNode* d2 = l2;
        
        while (d1 != d2) {
            d1 = (d1 == NULL) ? l2 : d1->next;
            d2 = (d2 == NULL) ? l1 : d2->next;
        }
        
        return d1;
    }
```

In the return statement, either d1 or d2 can be returned since they will meet at the intersection point or NULL if there's no intersection. The conditions for updating d1 and d2 are now properly placed after advancing them to the next nodes.